# Using W3C Document Object Model how to insert tag for particular text

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, w3c

For example i have html content like this.

```
<div>go to the text from here.<br> from there <br> Go to the text</div>
```

In the above content, i want to insert span tag for the word alone Like the below output using java.

I'm using org.w3c.dom package.

I tried but not able to make success

```
Element e = doc.createElement("span");
String text = preElement.getTextContent();
if(text.indexOf("text"){
e.setTextContent("text");
}
// Afterwards how to insert this to document. How to use insertBefore method for the //inbetween text.
```

Expected Output:

```
<div>go to the <span>text</span> from here.<br> from there <br> Go to the <span>text</span></div>
```

Please help.

Comment: In which language? Using which library, if applicable? And what makes `text` special?

Comment: @minitech java. org.w3c.dom. Not only span , i have insert anchor tag and many.similar to this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`splitText`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-38853C1D) method on your text node to split it into three nodes, isolating the word you need to wrap in your element. Then you only have to replace the text node you just isolated (use [`replaceChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-785887307)) with the new element. There is no need to create a new text node, you can simply put the one you removed in the element you added.

Java implementation reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Text.html#splitText%28int%29 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#replaceChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20org.w3c.dom.Node%29.